# Angular-cli build folder structure

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

The default angular-cli build generates dist folder with very flat structure - assets folder and js, html files. Is there a way to create fe. scripts folder and put all js files in it during build process?

Answer (score 9):

The CLI does not fully support this yet, but it does provides some helpful tools to get you much of the way there. I needed this to deploy my Angular application along with a WAR while trying to minimize the amount of complexity added via servlet-mappings. This question doesn't mention J2EE specifically, but I think that principles from this solution can be shared across various environments.

---

Relevant `ng build` parameters:

- `--deploy-url`: The path mapping which will be applied to resources. *This is probably as close as Angular-CLI currently gets to what you're looking for.*
- `--output-path`: Designates an output directory for the Angular build (in particular, I used this to designate unique output directories for different environments, since the application is being deployed to multiple targets with different configurations).
- `--base-href`: The root URI for the application. E.g., `/angular-app/` for `http://localhost:4200/angular-app/`. This sets the `<base href="<uri>">` head tag and is necessary for non-hash routing. It might be necessary for other things, too.

The most interesting one for you is probably `--deploy-url`. If you set a deploy URL of `/dist/`, for example, then the references to JS files in your built application will be prefixed with `/dist/`.

---

Two big catches to this method:

- `--deploy-url` does not change the *output* path for the JS files. It only changes the references to the JS files. The files themselves will still be put in the root build directory. You'll have to add a step to your build process to fix this manually.
- `--deploy-url` does not seem to work for any other assets. I place all of my other assets in the `assets/` directory, and the built output still refers to the assets via `assets/<path>` (rather than `dist/assets/<path>` as desired). You can work around this by providing a virtual directory or a URL rewrite.

---

For reference, here is my resulting directory structure for the WAR:

```
app/
    dist/    <-- Deployed Angular application
        assets/
            (images, CSS, etc)
        *.js
        (other assets pulled into the root path, e.g. *.(svg|eot|woff|woff2|ttf) from Font Awesome)
        index.html
    WEB-INF/
    ...
    index.jsp
```

These are the steps I take to produce this structure:

1. `ng build -pr false --prod --output-path build/node-prod --base-href /angular-app/ --deploy-url /angular-app/dist/`.
2. Copy contents of `build/node-prod` to the WAR build directory's `app/dist` via a gradle task.
3. Point `index.jsp` to `index.html` via the content `<%@include file="dist/index.html"%>`.
4. Add a servlet-mapping for the default servlet (static assets) for the paths `/dist/*` and `/assets/*`.
5. Add URL-mapping via http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/ for `^/assets/(.*)$` to `/dist/assets/$1` (or via httpd, nginx, etc.). This is needed because of the catch given above for `--deploy-url` not working for other assets.
6. (Optional) add 301 or 302 redirect for `^/dist/index.html$` to the root context path to prevent users accessing the app via the `dist` URI.

In the resulting webapp, `http://localhost/angular-app/` is the only valid endpoint to my application. This endpoint points to `index.jsp`, which includes the content of `index.html`, which loads the relevant JS via `<script src="/angular-app/dist/<some-file>.js"></script>` tags.

When some other asset is necessary, such as the logo image, the page makes a request to `assets/<file-name>`, which is rewritten server-side via Tuckey to `dist/assets/<file-name>`, transparently resolving to the requested asset.

The nice thing about this solution was that we were able to deploy the Angular application in the root context without having to put *everything* that `ng build` built into the root WAR path. This is especially nice because we don't want to add global servlet mappings (e.g., `*.js`) when they can be avoided.

Comment: the "ng build" arguments [ex: "--base-href /myapp/static/"] can be included in the BUILD section of your package.json: {
  "name": "myapp",  "version": "0.0.0",  "scripts": {    "ng": "ng",    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --base-href /myapp/static/", etc } ...snip... }