# Set build output folder based on file type with angular cli

Tags: angular, webpack, build, angular-cli

Webpack 5 can split build output into folders by type. For example, to put js and code maps in a separate folder (`/build/js`), one can have this in webpack config:

```
output: {
  filename: 'js/[name].[contenthash:8].js',
},
```

To put images and fonts inside folder called `media`:

```
{
  test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|ico|woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg|json)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
  type: 'asset/resource',
  generator: {
    filename: 'media/[name].[contenthash:8][ext]'
  }
},
```

For CSS:

```
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
  filename: 'css/[name].[contenthash:8].css',
  chunkFilename: 'css/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.css'
}),
```

Is it possible to achieve the same kind of flexibility offered by webpack, by using Angular CLI? By default (`ng new test`), it outputs everything into the same folder (`/build/test`), which on large projects is difficult to work with.

I checked similar Stack Overflow questions on this topic, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506450/angular-cli-build-folder-structure), they are either outdated (>5 years old) or don't have an answer. `ng eject` is no longer available in Angular.